# Splitting fields, eliminating zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}}, \sqrt{2 - i \sqrt{6}})$ equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}}, i\sqrt{6})$?

I mean, can we eliminate $\sqrt{2 - i \sqrt{6}}$ like this?

Comment: Have you found the polynomial and its roots?

Comment: Yes, roots are $x_1=\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}}$, $-x_1$, $x_3=\sqrt{2-i\sqrt{6}}$ and $-x_3$.

Comment: No, I was wondering can I reduce it like that. I know I can rewrite it like $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_1x_3)$ but then I was wondering can I maybe do this, can I just simple use $x_1$ and $x_1^2$

Comment: A spplitiing field a is the smallest field containing all roots of the polynomial in question. If you adjoint a root and somehow manage to get the other from it then both fields will be equal. You need to make sure is a root of the polynomial though.

Comment: Yes I know, but that is not answer to my question. I wrote roots. I was asking are those two equal because I am no sure.

Comment: Polynomial is $x^4-4x^2+10$. Nor is $\sqrt{10}$ but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}},\sqrt{2-i \sqrt{6}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}},\sqrt{10})$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, we cannot !

Let $2\theta=\arctan (\sqrt{6}/2)$, set

$F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{10}~\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i\theta}},\sqrt[4]{10}~\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{-i\theta}})$, $K=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[4]{10}~\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i\theta}},\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{2i\theta}}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{-2i\theta}})\right)$

Write $\zeta=\sqrt[4]{10}~\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i\theta}}$, then

$F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\bar{\zeta})$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,(\zeta^2-\bar{\zeta}^2)/2)$

Note that $\zeta^2-\bar{\zeta}^2\in\mathbb{Q}[\zeta,\bar{\zeta}]\subset F$, so we get $K\subset F$

Set $\alpha=\zeta,~\beta=(\zeta^2-\bar\zeta^2)/2$, we get $\gamma=\beta-\alpha^2/2=\bar\zeta^2/2\in K$

Thus, $\alpha\gamma=\sqrt{10}\bar\zeta/2\in K$, which implies $\sqrt{10}\bar\zeta\in K$

So $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\sqrt{10}\bar\zeta)$, which may be proper in $F$